# XWork / Domino : Is there a way to NOT log HTTP 500 Error to log.nsf?

Tags: xpages, lotus-domino

All 500 errors are written to log.nsf...that could be a lot in some cases.
Is there a notes.ini to disable this logging ?

Thanks

Comment: Just a thought: something is wrong with applications, if server throws too much HTTP 500 errors... Try to hunt them down. The best approach is to adopt try/catch error handling whenever possible and redirect them to OpenLog (or other logging mechanism).

Answer (score 0):

I agree with Frantisek. If you're server is throwing an 500 error something is going seriously wrong and you should investigate the issue instead of hiding it from your logs. Enable the Default error page checkbox so you can see a full trace log of things that go wrong. If that doesn't clear your issue look into the technical support directory on your server to investigate the logs.

Hiding an error from the log is NEVER a good idea.